{ "He" in "He left" is subject. } — The countable noun "subject" has no article here. How to explain this?
The textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 67:

There is one guard outside.
It’s clear that it’s a forgery.
In the existential example, the dummy (semantically empty) pronoun "there" is subject, while
"one guard" is displaced subject, and similarly in the extraposition example the dummy
pronoun "it" is subject and "that it’s a forgery" is extraposed subject.

Why do the noun phrases in bold not have any articles?
I think "subject" is a countable noun and, therefore, must have an article:
— if it were "a", it would mean "an example of a";
— if it were "the", that would mean such a type of subject is the only one in the sentence.
So I think using both "a" and "the" would be correct.
P.S.: As you see, the title example { "He" in "He left" is subject. } is different from those inside the post. I did so to make the title more clear and readable. I hope that will not affect anything.

Functional roles typically have no article. I imagine the authors see subject, displaced subject, and extraposed subject as possible roles in an analytical schema.   Instances can be spoken of qua instances with the article, but they can also be spoken of in terms of their schema function without  article.   So a player can be "a sweeper" or "sweeper for the team".
